# Why a 20-bit shift register only output last 8 bits?

Tags: arduino, spi, shift-register

I need to use a VFD driver with 20-bit shift register but it only works for the last 8 bits:

```
void loop() {
    uint16_t buf = 0xFFFF;
    swrite(buf);
    delay(500);
  }
}


void swrite(uint16_t x) {
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < nbit; i++) {
    digitalWrite(SDI, x & (1 << i));
    tCLK();
  }
  tLE();
}

void tLE() {
  digitalWrite(LE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LE, LOW);
}

void tCLK() {
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
}
```

My SDI input:

[image]

The result of output of 0x00FF instead of 0xFFFF.

Functional table:
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is `nbit`?

Comment: Note that even with the solutions provided, this will still only shift out 16 bits, not 20 as in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expaning on Justme's answer:

The Arduino digitalWrite function expects an 8-bit argument, so once i reaches 8, `(1 << i)` is truncated to 0.
One way to cure this problem would be to use the C tertiary operator, like so:

```
void swrite(uint16_t x) {
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < nbit; i++) {
    // digitalWrite(SDI, x & (1 << i)); // fails when i > 7 because x&(1<<i) is truncated to 8 bit
    digitalWrite(SDI, (x & (1 << i) ? 1 : 0));  // expression ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
    tCLK();
  }
  tLE();
}
```

however some people find that style of C code harder to read. Essentially the tertiary operator `?:` is a hidden if-then-else statement, where the `then` and `else` are limited to expression values instead of statements. Probably fine here, but can be surprising if you're not expecting it.
Personally here's how I would approach it:

```
// SPI write
// @pre nbit = number of bits to send
// @param[in] x = value to send
// @pre SDI = digital data output pin
void swrite(uint16_t x) {
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nbit; i++) {
    digitalWrite(SDI, (x & 0x01));
    x >>= 1; // shift x right by 1 bit
    tCLK(); // pulse the CLK pin (clock)
  }
  tLE(); // pulse the LE pin (latch enable)
}
```

This takes the least significant bit (rightmost bit) from x and sends it to SDI pin, then the value of x is shifted left. No need to calculate `1 << i` each time, just a simple left shift. Note that since x is being passed by value, the x inside swrite() is just a copy of whatever value was passed into swrite(), so we don't have to worry about the fact that our copy of x gets changed. We would only have to worry about the caller's x being changed if x had been passed by reference. I also changed the index i to an 8-bit value, since the number of bits is not going to reach 255, and the Arduino benefits from conserving memory.

Comment: I think it should be "shift right" ;) The code is correct, but the comment and description in text say "left".

Comment: Heh! I always get those mixed up, since I use the keyboard with both hands... (fixed)

Answer (score 3):

That Arduino digitalWrite takes in only an uint8_t as parameter for data. Everything above 0xFF your code is sending to it looks like 0. Only send 0 and 1 to it as needed, instead of 16-bit masks.